# Can i fit this type of tire

Tags: tire, rims, size, tyre-width

Am I able to fit 20x2.4 tires on my 20x2.175 Bmx rim? I dont know if im able to fit that type of tire beacause I want street tires

Comment: What is written on the side of the tyres you have now?  Probably something like 60-406 or 406-60 ?

Answer (score 2):

20x2.175 may be some arbitrary numbers on a rim, but it isn't a size or measurement.

Reasonable widths for a 2.4 start at around 23mm inner width or 28mm outer. This includes what most would consider all real street/dirt/park rims. Plenty of frames and forks in the world won't take a 2.4. Most of the time it's fairly straightforward to predict that based on the clearance you have now. It can also easily be a case where you have to dial the chain length to make it work.